# KIE workbench - missing TOOLS tab and data modeller

Tags: data-modeling, missing-data, workbench, kie

I am new to KIE Workbench and I am trying to create a test project following a step-by-step [LinkToTheGuide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/wb.Workbench.html#wb.UserManagement)
In this guide, step 9.2.3. Define Data Model, it asks me to select Data Modeller from the Tools menu.
In my Workbench I could not find this Tools menu nor Data Modeller...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N30D.png)

Comment: You are referring to jbpm version 6.0 guide and using jbpm version 6.2. Refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch09.html#wb.QuickStartDefineDataModel). It has been since move to 'New Item' section.

Comment: Thanks for the link.